# Group of chains hanging forever in celery

Tags: python, django, asynchronous, celery, django-celery

I am trying to build the following workflow in celery:

```
         (chainA)
task1 -- task2 -- task3--|  
                         |
         (chainB)        |  (group)    
task1 -- task2 -- task3--|-------------
                         |              
         (chainC)        |
task1 -- task2 -- task3--|

            .
            .
            .
```

I end up with this code:

```
list_chains = build_s_chains()
group(*list_chains)()
```

The moment the line group(*list_chains)() is executed everything stops and 
halts. Seems like a deadlock, no error thrown.

If I try to execute the chains in for loop everything works just fine, but if I execute them in a for loop I would not be able to connect another task at the end of the for loop. I know that that is the definition of chord, I tried chord as well, it is still blocking.

Checked my rabbitmq and backend result, everything seems fine since I can run the chains manually. It seems to me that this should be straightforward but I can not see the reason why it isn't working.
Any help is appreciated

chainA for example looks like this:

```
job_chain = (
                        process_task.s(chip_measurement_object.raw_result_ref,
                                       process_args,
                                       process_args['file_path'],
                                       process_args['meas_data'],
                                       process_args['marker_data'],
                                       process_args['session']
                                       ) |

                        update_marker_data.s() |

                        plot_task.s(chip_measurement_object.id) |

                        grade_task.s(chip_measurement_object.id) |

                        postgres_async_res_update.s(chip_measurement_object.id, self.input_args)
        )
```

as I mentioned job_chain.apply_async() will execute just fine however it hangs or blocks when multiple chains are within group.
I have seen the other answers and the documentation, according to them this should work.

and here are my celery settings:

```
# Sensible settings for celery
CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER = False
CELERY_ACKS_LATE = True
CELERY_TASK_PUBLISH_RETRY = True
CELERY_DISABLE_RATE_LIMITS = False

# By default we will not ignore result
# If you want to see results and try out tasks_old interactively, change it to False
# Or change this setting on tasks_old level
CELERY_IGNORE_RESULT = False
CELERY_SEND_TASK_ERROR_EMAILS = False
CELERY_TASK_RESULT_EXPIRES = 600
```

update:
When I set CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER=True then the group runs fine with the command

```
group(*chain_list)()
```

but it runs locally of course which is not what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using immutable or mutable signatures when you use group, after you create the chain.  For example:

```
res = group(job_chain.si(), job_chain.si())()
```

Comment: I had tried before, I get: AttributeError: '_chain' object has no attribute 'si'